# Oracle: How to group records by certain columns before fetching results

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift that looks like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
=======================================
123  | AB   | SSSS | TTTT | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
123  | AB   | SSTT | TSTS | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
123  | AB   | PQRS | WXYZ | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
123  | CD   | SSTT | TSTS | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
123  | CD   | PQRS | WXYZ | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
456  | AB   | GGGG | RRRR | OPQ  | RST
---------------------------------------
456  | AB   | SSTT | TSTS | PQR  | XYZ
---------------------------------------
456  | AB   | PQRS | WXYZ | PQR  | XYZ
```

I have another table that also has a similar structure and data.

From these tables, I need to select values that don't have 'SSSS' in col3 and 'TTTT' in col4 in (**edited**) *either of the tables*. I'd also need to group my results by the value in col1 and col2.

Here, I'd like my query to return:

```
123,CD
456,AB
```

I don't want `123, AB` to be in my results, since one of the rows corresponding to `123, AB` has SSSS and TTTT in col3 and col4 respectively. i.e, I want to omit items that have `SSSS` and `TTTT` in col3 and col4 in either of the two tables that I'm looking up.

I am very new to writing queries to extract information from a database, so please bear with my ignorance. I was told to explore `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, but I am not sure I understand their usage well enough yet.

The query I have looks like:

```
SELECT * from table1 join table2 on
table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND
table1.col2 = table2.col2
WHERE
col3 NOT LIKE 'SSSS' AND
col4 NOT LIKE 'TTTT'
GROUP BY col1,col2
```

However, this query throws an error: `col5 must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

I'm not sure how to proceed. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What you wrote is not true / incomplete. You wouldn't get the error message about col5 if it wasn't in the SELECT list of your query. When you post and you show what you tried, please show EXACTLY what you tried; otherwise we all just waste our time.

Comment: You're right - I had a `SELECT *` in my query. Modifying the question.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: you said you wanted to get only the first two columns (that is what you showed in your example). Please make sure you explain exactly what you need; if the example is incorrect, please fix that too.

Comment: Just so we clear. Do you want to get rid of  an entire group (`123 | AB` in this case) if at least one combination of `SSSS` and `TTTT` is found in that group?

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov Yes, that's correct. I don't want any of the `123, AB` rows to be considered if even one of the rows for `123, AB` has `SSSS` and `TTTT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you also want DISTINCT results. In this case a solution with MINUS is probably as efficient as any other (and, remember, MINUS automatically also means DISTINCT):

```
select col1, col2 from table_name             -- enter your column and table names here
minus
select col1, col2 from table_name where col3 = 'SSSS' and col4 = 'TTTT'
;
```

No need to group by anything!

With that said, here is a solution using GROUP BY. Note that the HAVING condition uses a non-trivial aggregate function - it is a COUNT() but what is counted is a CASE to take care of what was required. Note that **it is not necessary/required** that the aggregate function in the HAVING clause/condition be included in the SELECT list!

```
select   col1, col2
from     table_name
group by col1, col2
having count(case when col3 = 'SSSS' and col4 = 'TTTT' then 1 else null end) = 0
;
```

Comment: NOTE: Optimizer cost, as shown in an EXPLAIN PLAN, should not be relied on exclusively to judge query efficiency, especially when the plans are for two very different approaches. With that said, on the sample data provided, the optimizer cost for the MINUS solution is 6 (including the WITH clause to generate the test data); the optimizer cost of the GROUP BY solution with HAVING is 17, even without a join. The MINUS solution seems to be the more efficient one.

Comment: Yes, For some reason `join` was the first thing that sprang to mind to eliminate those rows. Your solution's neater. Plus we query table once, which should be better performance wise.

Comment: Using `minus` seems like a good start. However, my tables are very big, and my table to query is actually a join of two different tables:
`select col1, col2 from table1 join table2...`
So it's running _really_ slowly right now. Any advice on how to speed up? I'm including more details in the question.

Comment: You can try the MINUS and the GROUP BY (with the HAVING condition) on your actual data and see which seems faster. Advice... Do you have indexes on your columns? If your tables are big, and you do joins, and you need this extra processing... there may not be many good solutions!

Comment: I'm going to try `GROUP BY` now. `minus` has been running for hours with no results yet.
I'm not sure about the index. I'm a total database n00b, so I'm going to first have to look up how to find if there's an index.
I just edited my question to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [EXCEPT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNION.html) operator.
[EXCEPT and MINUS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNION.html) are two different versions of the same operator.

Here is the syntax of what your query should look like

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1           
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col3 = 'SSSS' AND col4 = 'TTTT';
```

One important consideration is to know if your desired answer requires either the and or OR operator. Do you want to see the records where col3 = 'SSSS' and col4 has a value different than col4 = 'TTTT'?

If the answer is no you should use the version below:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1           
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col3 = 'SSSS' OR col4 = 'TTTT';
```

You can learn more about the [MINUS or EXCEPT operator on the Amazon Redshift documentation here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNION.html)